# Ao exibir o resultado da soma de dois números obtive "[object HTMLInputElement]"

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando Javascript, e durante esse exemplo me deparei com um erro que não consegui resolver.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Somando Números</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Somando Valores</h1>
    <input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1"> +
    <input type="number" name="txtn2" id="txtn2">
    <input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
    <div id="res">Resultado</div>
    <script>
        function somar() {
            let tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1')
            let tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2')
            let res = window.document.getElementById('res')
            let n1 = Number(tn1.value)
            let n2 = Number(tn2.value)
            let s = n1 + n2
            res.innerHTML = `A soma entre ${tn1} e ${tn2} é ${res}`
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ao somar os números, o resultado que me aparece é isto:

> " A soma entre [object HTMLInputElement] e [object HTMLInputElement] é
>   [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Será que o que você quiz fazer não era `res.innerHTML = \`A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é ${s}\`` ?

Answer (score 5):

O problema não é a soma e sim o que você está somando.

`tn1` e `tn2` são referências para os inputs:

```
let tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1')
let tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2')
```

Já `res` é referencia para um div:

```
let res = window.document.getElementById('res')
```

O curioso é mais adiante no código você definiu `n1` e `n2` que são os valores dos input:

```
let n1 = Number(tn1.value)
let n2 = Number(tn2.value)
```

Também definiu `s` que é o resultado da soma:

```
let s = n1 + n2
```

Então para reparar o seu código basta colocar a linha:

```
res.innerHTML = `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é ${s}`
```

no lugar de:

```
res.innerHTML = `A soma entre ${tn1} e ${tn2} é ${res}`
```

```js
function somar() {
  let tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1');
  let tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2');
  let res = window.document.getElementById('res');
  let n1 = Number(tn1.value);
  let n2 = Number(tn2.value);
  let s = n1 + n2;
  // Aqui foi feita a modificação
  res.innerHTML = `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é ${s}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Somando Números</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Somando Valores</h1>
  <input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1"> +
  <input type="number" name="txtn2" id="txtn2">
  <input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
  <div id="res">Resultado</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AngustiVasques Uma sugestão para diminuir o código:`let n1 = +tn1.value;
            let n2 = +tn2.value;
            `

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Dependendo do que for digitado, nem sempre o `+` funciona da mesma maneira: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106701 - E existe ainda a opção de usar `parseInt`, que também tem diferenças em alguns casos: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090518 - Claro que se for digitado um número válido, tanto faz, mas dependendo de como vc quer tratar os casos especiais, faz diferença (e aí vc usa o que faz sentido, pois não é só porque o código ficou menor que necessariamente ficou "melhor")

Comment: Bom, obrigado à todos que ajudaram.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Sobre "código menor não ser necessariamente melhor": https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052