# sort em um objeto [java]

Tags: java, classificação, objetos

Salve galera, estou com uma duvida de um projeto que estou fazendo apenas para aprender mais sobre a linguagem.
seguinte, 
Tenho um ficheiro txt no qual eu tenho que ler ele e separar os diferentes conteudos (nome, Pais , heightdepth, acessibilidade,hostilidade, kmFromLondon, temperature, wonderValue e um facto sobre o local) depois dar output nele ordenadamente pelo "rating" da hospitalidade do local.

O que contem no ficheiro é isto:

```
Amazonia,Brazil,60,10,10,8100,30,4,The Amazon rainforest occupies some 5.5 million square kilometres of South America.
Iguassu Falls,Brazil|Argentina,82,11,50,10064,25,4,Two hundred and seventy waterfalls flow along nearly 3 kilometres of rivers.
Niagra Falls,USA|Canada,50,18,69,5804,20,4,Adventurous tourists can take a cruise on the river below into the falls' mist.
Giant's Causeway,Northern Ireland,12,19,17,592,15,2,Legend has it that is is a former 'walkway' to Scotland.
Great Barrier Reef,Australia,60,10,10,15292,28,4,Over 30 species of whale and 15000 species of fish live here.
Mount Everest,Tibet|Nepal,8840,7,95,7424,-10,4,The highest mountain on Earth is located in the Himalayas.
Mount Vesuvius,Italy,1281,18,95,1630,30,1,The only volcano in mainland Europe to have erupted in the last 100 years.
Old Faithful,USA,55,14,65,7432,118,2,Over half of the world's geysers are located in Yellowstone national park.
Sahara Desert,African Union,3445,14,84,3800,35,3,Covers part of North Africa and is almost the same size as the USA.
Great Rift Valley,African Union,1470,14,12,5887,25,4,The valley was formed by activity between tectonic plates 35 million years ago.
Gobi Desert,Mongolia|China,2700,9,84,7279,30,3,The desert has been the location of many fossil finds.
Ngorongoro Crater,Tanzania,610,14,19,5804,30,2,Home to almost 25000 animals including masses of flamingoes around Lake Magadi.
Perito Morena Glacier,Argentina,60,9,82,13230,-5,3,The 5 kilometre wide glacier is well known for its process of rupturing.
Mount Fuji,Japan,3776,13,69,8671,25,2,Although classed as active its last eruption was in 1707.
Mont Blanc,Italy|France,4808,18,85,808,0,2,The highest mountain in Europe and a popular skiing destination.
The Dead Sea,Israel|Jordan,418,13,91,3666,25,1,The lowest point on the surface of the Earth and is really two large lakes.
The Matterhorn,France|Italy|Switzerland,4478,17,85,840,-5,2,Not the highest mountain in the Alps but perhaps the most breathtaking.
Uluru,Australia,346,10,70,14993,35,4,A massive monolith made from sandstone infused with minerals that reflect in the sunlight.
Lake Baikal,Russia,1637,8,55,6613,-30,2,An immense depth of 1637 metres and contains 20% of the worlds fresh water.
Kilauea,The Hawaiian Islands,1247,9,65,11783,30,3,Hawaiian legend considers the island to be the home of a volcano goddess.
Guilin Caves,China,220,9,16,9101,30,2,The people of Guilin have had to take refuge in them during times of conflict.
Giant Sequoia,USA,84,15,2,8570,30,2,The largest species of tree found only in California.
Mount Erebus,Antarctica,3794,4,95,17059,-49,3,Has continually erupted since 1972 and has a permanent lava lake within its summit.
Grand Canyon,USA,1600,15,80,8296,30,4,A vast and breathtaking spectacle stretching across the Arizona desert.
```

entao seguinte, criei um objeto dessa maneira,

```java
public class Wonders {
    String name;
    List countries = new ArrayList();
    int heightDepth;
    int accessibility;
    int hostility;
    int kmFromLondon;
    int temperature;
    int wonderValue;
    String fact;
    List compare = new ArrayList();
```

e depois

```java
        String unftxt[];
        unftxt = new String[24];
        Wonders w[] = new Wonders[unftxt.length];



        try (Scanner sfile = new Scanner(new File(fName))) {

           while(sfile.hasNextLine()){
               unftxt[ctrl] = sfile.nextLine();
               ctrl++;
           }//end while .hasnextLine()
        }//try

        for(int i=0;i<unftxt.length;i++){
            String[] parts = unftxt[i].split(",");
            w[i] = new Wonders();
            w[i].name = parts[0];
            w[i].countries.add(Arrays.toString(parts[1].split("\\|")));
            w[i].heightDepth = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            w[i].accessibility = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
            w[i].hostility = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
            w[i].kmFromLondon = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);
            w[i].temperature = Integer.parseInt(parts[6]);
            w[i].wonderValue = Integer.parseInt(parts[7]);
            w[i].fact = parts[8];

        }
```

sou novo na programaçao, estou a algumas horas parado neste problema, a minha pergunta é: como que vou ordenar a array de objeto w pela hospitalidade e se a hospitalidade for igual ordenar pela hospitalidade e pelo pais

Comment: 1) Trabalhe com listas em vez de arrays, são mais flexíveis. 2) pesquise na documentação da API um método `sort` que recebe um `Comparator` e aprenda a criar um para usar nesse método (ou melhor ainda, faça sua classe `Wonders` implementar a interface `Comparable`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é tua classe `Wonders` implementar a interface `Comparable`. Ela vai te obrigar a implementar o método `compareTo(T o)`.

O método `compareTo(T o)` é chamado da seguinte forma:

```
int result = object.compareTo(otherObject)
```

Desta forma o retorno será:

- -1 se o objeto da esquerda for menor
- 0 se os objetos forem iguais
- 1 se o objeto da esquerda for maior

Uma forma de implementar na tua classe este método, seria:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class Wonders implements Comparable<Wonders> {

  private String name;
  private List   countries = new ArrayList();
  private int    heightDepth;
  private int    accessibility;
  private int    hostility;
  private int    kmFromLondon;
  private int    temperature;
  private int    wonderValue;
  private String fact;
  private List   compare   = new ArrayList();

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Wonders other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other, "Outro objeto não pode ser nulo.");

    Integer thisHostility = this.hostility;
    Integer otherHostility = other.getHostility();

    int resultHostility = thisHostility.compareTo(otherHostility);

    if (resultHostility == 0) {

      if (Objects.nonNull(name) && Objects.isNull(other.name)) {
        return -1;
      } else if (Objects.isNull(name) && Objects.nonNull(other.name)) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
      }
    } else {
      return resultHostility;
    }
   }
      ... // getters e setters aqui
    }
```

Este `compareTo(T o)` que implementei, ordena primeiro por `hostility`, e se forem iguais ordena por `name`.

Obs: não fiz a ordenação do segundo campo por país, pois tu tens uma lista de países. Aí fiquei na dúvida de como tu gostaria de ordenar pela listagem.

Depois tu tens que alterar o teu array `Wonders` por um `TreeSet<Wonders>`. O `TreeSet` vai te garantir a ordenação dos elementos a partir do método `compareTo(T o)` implementado na tua classe `Wonders`.

```
String unftxt[];
unftxt = new String[24];
Set<Wonders> wonders = new TreeSet<>();

try (Scanner sfile = new Scanner(new File(""))) {
  int ctrl = 0;

  while (sfile.hasNextLine()) {
    unftxt[ctrl] = sfile.nextLine();
    ctrl++;
  } 
}  catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

Wonders wonder;

for (int i = 0; i < unftxt.length; i++) {
  String[] parts = unftxt[i].split(",");
    wonder = new Wonders();
    wonder.setName(parts[0]);
    wonder.setCountries(Arrays.asList((parts[1].split("\\|")))); 
    wonder.setHeightDepth(Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
    wonder.setAccessibility(Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));
    wonder.setHostility(Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
    wonder.setKmFromLondon(Integer.parseInt(parts[5]));
    wonder.setTemperature(Integer.parseInt(parts[6]));
    wonder.setWonderValue(Integer.parseInt(parts[7]));
    wonder.setFact(parts[8]);
}

for (Wonders w : wonders) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", w.getHostility(), w.getName()));
```

}

Comment: Para um campo `int` (ou qualquer outro tipo primitivo), não faz sentido verificar se é nulo - no caso do `hostility`, será feito o autoboxing para `Integer`, e ele nunca será nulo (pois `int`, por *default*, é inicializado com zero, então sempre terá um valor - [veja](https://ideone.com/XvPOxv)). E dentro da classe não precisa usar o *getter* para acessar os membros do `other`. Resumindo, a comparação entre `hostility` poderia se resumir a `int resultHostility = Integer.compare(hostility, other.hostility)`. E para acessar o nome, pode usar `other.name` (não precisa do *getter*).

Comment: Tens razão, criei o wrapper por para poder utilizar o `compareTo(T t)` mas esqueci que estava com primitivos na hora da comparação.
Valeu por avisar, editei o comentário.

Comment: Também não precisa atribuir o valor a um `Integer`, esta classe possui um método estático que compara dois valores `int` diretamente: `Integer.compare(hostility, other.hostility)` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-

Comment: Este realmente nunca usei... dá para poupar algumas linhas utilizando ele.

Comment: Não é questão de economizar linhas, e sim de fazer coisas que não precisa. No caso, ao fazer `Integer thisHostility = this.hostility;` vc está criando um objeto `Integer` desnecessário (fora o fato de [ocupar mais memória que um `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420032)), pois dá pra fazer a mesma coisa diretamente com os valores `int`, então não tem motivo nenhum para usar o `Integer` ali. Talvez a questão da memória seja insignificante em um programa tão pequeno, mas a questão principal é código mais claro, conciso, sem linhas desnecessárias: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052

Comment: De qualquer forma, +1 pela resposta :-)

Comment: Perfeito, concordo plenamente com teu apontamento.
Obrigado

Comment: Obrigado rapaziada me ajudou muito +1