# Como posso reduzir ainda mais a forma de escrever as rotas?

Tags: javascript

sou novo ainda nesses lados e estou fazendo uma aplicação em node (eu acho...). Tenho escrito as minhas rotas dessa forma exemplo:

```
routes.get('/produtos', mostrarProdutos)
routes.get('/produtos/:id', mostrarPorId)
routes.post('/produtos', novoProduto)
```

Então estava enrolando por ai e fiz um teste que deu certo dessa forma:

```
routes.get('/produtos', mostrarProdutos)
      .get('/produtos/:id', mostrarPorId)
      .post('/produtos', novoProduto)
```

É boa prática dessa última forma? Dá algum problema? Tem alguma forma de diminuir ainda mais?

Comment: Para que reduzir ainda mais? Código menor não é necessariamente melhor, sugiro que leia o primeiro parágrafo [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052) :-)

Comment: É, hkotsubo tem razão, já ouvi falar algo parecido faz algum tempo. Só perguntei isso para ver se teria como eu otimizar meu tempo e não ficar escrevendo código parecido em uma aplicação bem maior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há problema algum em implementar dessa maneira.

O que acontece é que este object segue um padrão chamado *[Fluent Builder Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/fluent-builder-pattern)*, ou *Padrão de Construtor Fluente*, onde cada método retorna a instância atual do objeto após a realização das ações. Assim você pode invocar um novo método a seguir, em uma única linha.

Quanto ao tamanho, acredito que este seja o formato funcional mais compacto possível.