# Validação dos 2 últimos dígitos de CPF em um único laço for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu fazendo a verificação dos dois últimos dígitos para validação de CPF.

Fiz o código, mas só está calculando o primeiro dígito. Não estou conseguindo, incluir no mesmo laço para calcular o segundo dígito:

```py
    while True:

    #CPF deve ser inserido sem formatação Ex.16695835009
    cpf = input("Informe o seu CPF: ")

    if len(cpf) != 11 or not cpf.isnumeric():
        print("Dados inseridos incorretamente.\nDigite novamente.")
        continue

    novo_cpf = cpf[:-2]
    soma_digitos = 0
    lista_digitos = []

    for key, index in enumerate(novo_cpf):
        key_reverso = len(novo_cpf) + 1 - key
        lista_digitos.append(key_reverso * int(index))
        soma_digitos += lista_digitos[key]

    d = 11 - (soma_digitos % 11)

    if(d > 9):
        d = 11 - d

    '''
    Os prints abaixo é só para verificação da saída do código.
    '''
    print(lista_digitos)
    print(soma_digitos)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Só de curiosidade, pq quer incluir no mesmo laço?

Comment: @Bacco, na vdd o exercício pede para ser feito a verificação do CPF informado pelo usuário. Em nenhum momento, pede para que seja feita no mesmo laço. Sou iniciante na linguagem Python e pensei que se incluísse a verificação do segundo dígito no mesmo laço, seria menos código e assim poupasse a repetição do laço `for` novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até dá para fazer tudo com um único laço, só não sei se faz **tanta** diferença assim. Mas antes vamos tentar fazer com dois laços, aí comparamos com a versão "um-laço-só".

---

Antes dos laços em si, você já poderia converter a string em uma lista de números, na qual cada elemento desta lista é um dígito. Para isso podemos usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) e [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
def validar_cpf(cpf):
    if len(cpf) != 11:
        return False

    try:
        digitos = list(map(int, cpf))
    except ValueError:
        return False

    # restante da validação...
```

Assim, se algum caractere da string não puder ser convertido para número, ele cai no bloco `except` e a função já retorna `False`. Fiz assim porque posteriormente eu vou precisar converter esses caracteres para número, para poder fazer os cálculos do dígito verificador. Ao mesmo tempo, eu já valido se a string de fato contém dígitos.

Também escolhi desta forma porque [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) pode retornar `True` para vários caracteres que dão erro ao serem convertidos para número com `int()`, como por exemplo o `½` ([VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bd/index.htm)) - [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/0AyHGW) a lista completa - então eu acho essa verificação melhor do que simplesmente usar `isnumeric()` (com a vantagem de que já cria a lista com os caracteres convertidos para números, pois vou precisar desses números posteriormente). Como é o usuário que está digitando os dados, existe a possibilidade dele digitar algum desses caracteres, então já fazemos esta verificação logo no início.

---

Agora sim, aos cálculos. Primeiro vamos fazer a versão com 2 *loops* (o algoritmo pode ser facilmente buscado na internet, eu usei [este site](https://www.geradorcpf.com/algoritmo_do_cpf.htm) como fonte):

```
def validar_cpf(cpf):
    if len(cpf) != 11:
        return False

    try:
        digitos = list(map(int, cpf))
    except ValueError:
        return False

    def calcula_digito(multiplicador):
        total = 0
        for d in digitos:
            if multiplicador >= 2:
                total += d * multiplicador
                multiplicador -= 1
            else: break
        resto = total % 11
        if resto < 2:
            return 0
        else:
            return 11 - resto

    # primeiro dígito não bate, CPF inválido
    if digitos[9] != calcula_digito(10):
        return False

    # segundo dígito não bate, CPF inválido
    if digitos[10] != calcula_digito(11):
        return False

    return True
```

Eu criei a [*inner function*](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) `calcula_digito`, que contém o *loop* para calcular o dígito verificador. Para o primeiro dígito verificador, começamos com 10, que é multiplicado pelo primeiro dígito do CPF, depois multiplicamos o segundo dígito por 9, o terceiro por 8, etc (parando no 2, por isso o `if multiplicador >= 2`, e um `break` para interromper o *loop* caso o multiplicador seja menor que 2).

No segundo dígito verificador, eu faço o mesmo algoritmo, mas começando a multiplicar por 11. A lógica do *loop* é a mesma, e por isso eu reaproveitei o código da função interna `calcula_digito`. Mas como essa função é chamada duas vezes, então estou fazendo dois laços.

---

Repare que o que muda de um *loop* para outro é somente o valor inicial do multiplicador (10 para o primeiro, 11 para o segundo), e a condição de parada é a mesma (vou até o valor do multiplicador ser `2`). Sendo assim, seria possível fazer tudo em um único *loop*:

```
def validar_cpf(cpf):
    if len(cpf) != 11:
        return False

    try:
        digitos = list(map(int, cpf))
    except ValueError:
        return False

    def calcula_resto(resto):
        if resto < 2:
            return 0
        else:
            return 11 - resto

    total1 = total2 = 0
    multiplicador = 11
    for d in digitos:
        if multiplicador >= 2:
            if multiplicador >= 3:
                total1 += d * (multiplicador - 1)
            total2 += d * multiplicador
            multiplicador -= 1
        else: break

    # primeiro dígito não bate, CPF inválido
    if digitos[9] != calcula_resto(total1 % 11):
        return False

    # segundo dígito não bate, CPF inválido
    if digitos[10] != calcula_resto(total2 % 11):
        return False

    return True
```

Eu aproveito o mesmo *loop* para calcular o somatório referente a ambos os dígitos verificadores (tanto iniciando com 11 quanto com 10), e em seguida calculo os respectivos dígitos usando o resto da divisão segundo as regras do algoritmo.

---

[Neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/420692/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dos-2-%C3%BAltimos-d%C3%ADgitos-de-cpf-em-um-%C3%BAnico-la%C3%A7o-for#comment817835_420692) você disse que queria fazer tudo em um único *loop*, pois assim "seria menos código". Bom, olhe novamente para as funções acima e veja se o ganho foi realmente significativo (na minha opinião, não foi, é praticamente a mesma quantidade de código).

Mas o ponto não é "escrever menos código". [Um código mais curto não é necessariamente "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052), assim como um código mais longo não é necessariamente "pior". Primeiro procure escrever um código claro e correto, e depois você pensa nessas otimizações.

Se está preocupado com o desempenho, sinceramente, esses *loops* não são tão custosos assim e para a grande maioria dos casos a diferença será irrelevante. Em sistemas reais você faz testes de desempenho para ver onde estão os gargalos e não se preocupa com essas micro-otimizações (até porque em sistemas reais, na grande maioria das vezes, *provavelmente* o gargalo não estará nesses *loops* menores).

Pense também na manutenção do código: futuramente pode ser que uma outra pessoa (ou até mesmo você) tenha que mexer no código, então o melhor é que ele esteja claro quanto ao que é feito. Claro que pode ser uma questão de opinião se o algoritmo fica melhor expresso com um *loop* ou dois, mas você não deveria escrever um código que fica confuso e difícil de entender e manter, **só porque** ficou menor (o tamanho do código não deve ser um objetivo em si, há outros pontos a se considerar).

---

Conforme [comentado pelo Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/420692/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dos-2-%C3%BAltimos-d%C3%ADgitos-de-cpf-em-um-%C3%BAnico-la%C3%A7o-for/420771#comment817960_420771), daria para otimizar o segundo *loop*, pois o primeiro elemento é multiplicado por 11, sendo que no final pegamos o resto da divisão por 11, então este elemento não influencia no resultado final. Portanto, o segundo *loop* poderia começar do segundo dígito em diante:

```
def validar_cpf(cpf):
    if len(cpf) != 11:
        return False

    try:
        digitos = list(map(int, cpf))
    except ValueError:
        return False

    # incluir o índice no qual começa o loop
    def calcula_digito(multiplicador, inicio = 0):
        total = 0
        for d in digitos[inicio:]:
            if multiplicador >= 2:
                total += d * multiplicador
                multiplicador -= 1
            else: break
        resto = total % 11
        if resto < 2:
            return 0
        else:
            return 11 - resto

    # primeiro dígito não bate, CPF inválido
    if digitos[9] != calcula_digito(10):
        return False

    # segundo dígito não bate, CPF inválido
    if digitos[10] != calcula_digito(10, 1): # começa o loop do segundo elemento
        return False

    return True
```

Agora a função `calcula_digito` pode receber o índice no qual o *loop* será iniciado (ou zero, se nenhum for indicado - lembrando que listas começam no índice zero).

`digitos[inicio:]` constrói uma sub-lista a partir do índice `inicio`. Claro que eu poderia fazer um `if inicio == 0:` faço o `for` em `digitos`, e se `inicio` for um valor diferente, aí eu crio a sub-lista (assim evito de criar uma sub-lista à toa, quando o índice for zero).

Outra alternativa é usar um `while`:

```
def calcula_digito(multiplicador, inicio = 0):
    total = 0
    indice = inicio
    while True:
        if multiplicador >= 2:
            total += digitos[indice] * multiplicador
            multiplicador -= 1
            indice += 1
        else: break
    resto = total % 11
    if resto < 2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 11 - resto
```

Assim, evito a criação de sub-listas. De qualquer forma, repare que as alterações são mais no sentido de criar ou não novas estruturas à toa, se isso faz mais sentido ou não de acordo com o contexto, etc, e o que menos importa aqui é se o código vai ficar menor.

Comment: De curiosidade, com 2 loops ainda dá pra pular a casa `* 11` do segundo loop (pq cá entre nós, multiplicar por onze para tirar o resto da divisão por onze é meio sem sentido).

Comment: @Bacco Tem razão, atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: @hkotsubo Isso não é uma resposta, mas sim uma aula de como escrever corretamente um código, pensando em todos os lados. Foi muito esclarecedora e motivadora. Ainda não vi no curso de Python que estou fazendo algumas coisas como `map` e como tratar exceções, para falar a verdade, entrei no capítulo de funções por agora. Então, ainda tenho um longo caminho a percorrer na linguagem.