# Contar quantos elementos estão duplicados em uma string

Tags: javascript, array, string, loop

O propósito é contabilizar o número de elementos que estão repetidos em uma `string` e não apenas verificar se há elementos duplicados ou contar quantas vezes esses elementos aparecem.

Por exemplo:

```
"aabbca1m" // 2 (a,b)
"aABCbc33zzzzzqw" // 5 (a,b,c,3,z)
```

Consegui montar um código, mas ele contabiliza quantas vezes os caracteres repetidos aparecem em cada volta do loop.

```js
function duplicateCount(text) {
    text = text.toLocaleLowerCase().split("").sort()
    let text2 = text

    let count = 0
    for (let index = 0; index < text.length; index++) {
        for (let chave = index + 1; chave < text2.length; chave++) {
            if (text[index] == text2[chave]) {
                count++
            }
        }
    }

    return count
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabBcdeaa")) //deveria resultar em 2, porém resulta em 7
```

Comment: você quer pegar o que mais se repete e mostrar o valor?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não, quero pegar a quantidade de elementos que estão repetidos. Igual coloquei nos dois exemplos.

Comment: tá muito confuso os exemplos! tem como ser mais claro?

Comment: Porque aqui teria que ser *2*: `aabBcdeaa` é estranho isso

Comment: @VirgilioNovic veja bem essa string: "aabBcdeaa", os únicos elementos que estão repetidos aqui são o 'a' e o 'b', ou seja, 2 elementos repetidos. Talvez fique mais claro se eu editar a pergunta e explicar que é independente estar em maiúsculo ou minúsculo.

Comment: Não tá claro porque no final dessa texto tem mais dois `aa`!?

Comment: Amigo, é uma string qualquer, entende? Poderia ser "casa", por exemplo. O resultado seria 1, no caso. Já que o único caracter que repete é o 'a'. No exemplo "aabBcdeaa", os únicos elementos que repetem são o 'b' e o 'a', totalizando 2 caracteres que estão duplicados dentro da string. Não consigo ser mais claro que isso.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode criar um objeto que armazena todas as letras da string, seguida do número de ocorrências do caractere. Em seguida, basta retornar o número de propriedades desse objeto cujo valor, isto é, o número de aparições do caractere, for maior que 1.

Algo assim:

```js
function duplicateCount(string) {
  const charMap = {};
  
  // Mapeamos cada caractere da string ao nosso mapa.
  for (const char of string.toLowerCase()) {
    if (!charMap[char]) {
      charMap[char] = 1;
    } else {
      charMap[char] = charMap[char] + 1;
    }
  }
  
  // Obtemos todos os valores do nosso mapa e os filtramos,
  // de modo a manter somente aqueles números maiores que 1.
  const repeatedValues = Object.values(charMap)
    .filter((count) => count > 1);
    
  return repeatedValues.length;
}

console.log(duplicateCount('aabbca1m')); // 2
console.log(duplicateCount('aABCbc33zzzzzqw')); // 5
```

É importante esclarecer que `Object.values` retorna um *array* com os valores do objeto. Por exemplo:

```js
const values = Object.values({
  a: 2,
  b: 1,
  c: 2,
  d: 3
});

console.log(values);
```

#### Outras abordagens:

Você pode reduzir o `if`/`else` do excerto acima, se preferir:

```js
function duplicateCount(string) {
  const charMap = {};

  for (const char of string.toLowerCase()) {
/*5*/   charMap[char] = (charMap[char] || 0) + 1;
  }

  return Object.values(charMap).filter((count) => count > 1).length;
}

console.log(duplicateCount('aabbca1m')); // 2
console.log(duplicateCount('aABCbc33zzzzzqw')); // 5
```

Se você ficou confuso com a expressão `(charMap[char] || 0) + 1` na linha 5, é basicamente um jogo de expressões:

- Caso `charMap[char]` já esteja definido, será um número. Então, somaremos `1` ao seu valor atual.
- Caso `charMap[char]` não exista, iremos somar `1` à `0`. Nesse caso, `0` foi o valor que definimos como um tipo *fallback* através do operador lógico OR (`||`).

Você também pode utilizar o [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para fazer a mesma coisa. Só acho que o código a seguir, em alguns casos, pode não ser o mais ideal, principalmente se você estiver trabalhando com outras pessoas que possam, por ventura, não ter um domínio tão grande do JavaScript. De todo modo:

```js
function duplicateCount(string) {
  const map = [...string.toLowerCase()].reduce(
    (map, char) => ({
      ...map,
      [char]: (map[char] || 0) + 1
    }),
    {}
  );

  return Object.values(map).filter((count) => count > 1).length;
}

console.log(duplicateCount('aabbca1m')); // 2
console.log(duplicateCount('aABCbc33zzzzzqw')); // 5
```

#### Para um maior aprofundamento:

- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values);
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Achei válida sua solução, a única razão que não irei dá-la por finalizada é por que espero encontrar uma resposta mais enxuta.

Comment: @zangs, o que você classifica como "enxuta"? Posso editar a resposta de modo a adicionar outras soluções, se você tentar me definir o que esse termo significa para você.

Comment: Luiz, sua resposta foi muito satisfatória, apenas para deixar claro. Eu queria ver se alguém conseguiria uma resposta mais "curta" e funcional (caso isso seja possível) entende?

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, adicionando mais duas possibilidades "curtas". Agora está _enxuto_? :D

Comment: @zangs A primeira solução, na minha opinião, já é bem enxuta e com um código bem claro e legível. Como vc pode ver, a solução com `reduce`, apesar de menor, não é necessariamente "melhor" (vai da opinião de cada um, eu particularmente acho que fica um pouco mais difícil de entender e não vale a pena essa complicação a mais se o único objetivo é deixar o código mais curto). Enfim, [código menor não é necessariamente "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo concordo totalmente com você, tanto que deixei claro que a resposta dele era satisfatória, era mais uma questão de explorar outras respostas.

Comment: @LuizFelipe excelente cara! Grato pelo tempo e feedback :)

Comment: é brincadeira perceber que a gente se esforça, bota aquela resposta sem entender o que o cara quer e ainda por cima de tudo vem aqui dizer que a resposta é simplesmente satisfatória, vale lembrar que quem pergunta não sabe a resposta e como pode avaliar se existe uma resposta mais curta sendo a melhor? @LuizFelipe você fez excelente soluções e não merecia determinados comentários #desabafo.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) **`/(.)(?=.*\1)/gi`** para encontrar os caracteres que se repetem.

```js
function duplicateCount(text) {
  let repetidos = [...text.match(/(.)(?=.*\1)/gi)].map(x => x.toLowerCase());
  return (new Set(repetidos)).size;
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabBcdeaa"));                       // 2 => a,b
console.log(duplicateCount("aABCbc33zzzzzqw"));                 // 5 = > a,b,c,3,z
console.log(duplicateCount("faaaAbCbc33zzzzzqwbb3c3c3c3c3cf")); // 6 = > f,a,b,c,3,z
```

A lógica é simples, a expressão regular **`/(.)(?=.*\1)/gi`** percorre a string e apenas estabelece um grupo de captura caso o caractere possua repetições a sua frente([look-ahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-ahead_(backtracking))).

Na expressão **`(.)`** os parenteses `()` significam que deva estabelecer um grupo de captura para `.` que corresponde a qualquer caractere  que não seja retorno de linha.

Já a expressão **`(?=.*\1)`** é o [look-ahead](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds), significa que a expressão anterior **`(.)`** só será capturada se a condição `.*\1` for atendida. `.*` corresponde a zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam retorno de linha e `\1` uma ocorrência do grupo de captura que pretende se estabelecer.

> Obs: *Na expressão regular* **`/(.)(?=.*\1)/gi`** *a correspondência sempre é obtida, o grupo* `(.)` *e é estabelecida para*
>   *comparação posterior e a correspondência é aceita ou não dependendo da*
>   *correspondência observada no look-ahead* `(?=.*\1)` *.*

No final a expressão regular possui duas flags **`gi`** onde `g` significa que captura dentro da string é global ou seja não para na primeira ocorrência e i que faz a captura ser caso insensitivo não distinguindo maiúsculas de minusculas.

Depois de formar a array com todos os caracteres repetidos eles [são convertidos para minúsculas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), essa array é convertida em um objeto [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) que permite apenas que sejam armazenados valores únicos implicando que o [tamanho](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) desse `Set` é quantidade de caracteres repetidos.

Comment: Vale lembrar que `\w` só considera letras, números e o caractere `_`. Se bem que a pergunta não deixa claro o que deve ser considerado (ela só deu exemplos com letras, mas ao mesmo tempo fala em "elementos repetidos", o que *pode dar a entender* que é qualquer caractere). Se bem que não seria difícil adaptar a regex para aceitar qualquer coisa... E acho que nem precisa do `+` depois do `\1`, pois se tiver uma única ocorrência de `\1`, já indica que ele se repete.

Comment: @hkotsubo, Eu construí a expressão no que entendi no que entendida pergunta mas poderia ser feita com qualquer coisa que não seja espaço e newline ou então qualquer coisa que não seja newline. Realmente não precisa do `+` apos `\1`,  eu parti duma expressão mais simples cujo a intenção era consumir toda uma cadeia de repetições, mas vou corrigir pois realmente basta encontrar uma repetição para satisfazer a condição.

Comment: Ah sim, é que a pergunta - pelo que entendi - não deixa claro quais os caracteres que de fato devem ser considerados, o que dá margem para interpretações diferentes. Isso não quer dizer que sua resposta está errada...

Comment: @hkotsubo Feito troquei o grupo de captura, você tem razão, realmente é mais completo usar `.` ao invés de `\w`

Comment: Blz, já tinha votado antes e mantenho meu voto :-) Só um detalhe (porque sou pedante): "*a expressão anterior `(.)` só será capturada se a condição `.*\1` for atendida.*" - na verdade o grupo `(.)` sempre será capturado se encontrar um caractere (ele não depende do lookahead para ser capturado). Depois que o grupo é capturado, a condição `.*\1` é verificada, e se ela não for atendida, a regex falha. E faz sentido, não tem como o *lookahead* saber o que é `\1` se ele não tiver sido capturado antes.

Comment: Isso correspondência sempre é obtida, o grupo é estabelecido para comparação posterior e a captura é aceita ou não dependendo da correspondência observada no look-ahead.

Answer (score 3):

Depois de ajustar a ordem dos caracteres com `.split()` + `.sort()` + `.join()` poderia fazer um `while` que vai rodar de `0` até o tamanho da string, pegando caracteres distintos. Dentro do `while` você usa uma expressão regular que irá selecionar, a cada volta do laço, os caracteres repetidos e contar com `.length`. Se for maior que `1` significa que o caractere é repetido, e então a variável que controla o `while` será incrementada pelo tamanho `.length` do que a expressão regular capturou, caso contrário, será incrementado normalmente com `++`.

Por exemplo, a string `aabBcdeaa` irá virar `aaaabbcde`. Na primeira volta do laço, a regex irá capturar os 4 "a". Como 4 é maior que 1, irá incrementar a contagem na variável `count` com `++` e também irá incrementar a variável `i` com `4` (tamanho da string capturada pela regex). Então o `i` (que inicialmente tinha o valor `0`) passará a ter o valor `4` (`0+4`) e a próxima volta do `while` irá pegar agora o primeiro caractere "b", e fará a mesma coisa. A regex irá pegar "bb", que tem 2 de `length`, e irá somar `++` na variável `count` e somar `+2` na variável `i`.

Na próxima volta irá começar do caractere "c", e a regex irá retornar o tamanho `1`, ou seja, o "c" é único, logo a variável `count` não será afetada e a variável `i` será incrementada somente com `++`. Isso tudo que estou explicando você verá no código mais abaixo.

A regex `text[i]+"+"` pega o respectivo caractere iterado pelo laço `while` na string e agrupa se houver mais de 1 (sinal de `+`). Por exemplo, na primeira volta do `while`, sendo a string `aaaabbcde`, irá retornar uma array com os 4 "a":

```
["aaaa"]
```

Ao fazer `text.match(re)[0].length` irá retornar o tamanho da string contida no único item da array retornada (índice `[0]`), que é `4`.

**Veja o exemplo:**

```js
function duplicateCount(text) {
   text = text.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
   let count = i = 0;
   while(i < text.length){
      // escapar possíveis caracteres especias da regex
      let str = text[i].replace(/[\.*+?^${}()|[\]]/g, '\\$&');
      let len = text.match(str + "+")[0].length;
      len > 1 ? (count++, i += len) : i++;
   }
   return count;
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabBcdeaa")); // 2 -> a, b
console.log(duplicateCount("casa")) // 1 -> a
console.log(duplicateCount("c_asabfgbf_")) // 4 -> _, a, b, f
console.log(duplicateCount("13451090836")) // 3 -> 0, 1, 3
console.log(duplicateCount("aABCbc33zzzzzqw((")) // 6 -> 3, a, b, c, z, (
console.log(duplicateCount("-,-\^\^((")) // 3 -> -, ^, (
```

Repare que no último `console.log` é repetido a barra invertida 2 vezes (`duplicateCount("-,-\^\^((")`) mas ela não é contabilizada por ser um caractere de escape.

---

Outra opção usando `.indexOf()` e `.lastIndexOf()`:

Como `.indexOf()` retorna a posição do primeiro caractere encontrado e `.lastIndexOf()` a última, se houver o mesmo caractere mais de uma vez, os valores serão diferentes, mas se o caractere não for repetido, os dois métodos retornarão o mesmo valor.

```js
function duplicateCount(text) {
   text = text.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
   let count = i = 0;
   while(i < text.length){
      let p1 = text.indexOf(text[i]);
      let p2 = text.lastIndexOf(text[i]);
      var len = text.substr(p1,p2-p1+1).length;
      len != 1 ? (count++, i += len) : i++;
   }
   return count;
}

console.log(duplicateCount("aabBcdeaa")); // 2 -> a, b
console.log(duplicateCount("casa")) // 1 -> a
console.log(duplicateCount("c_asabfgbf_")) // 4 -> _, a, b, f
console.log(duplicateCount("13451090836")) // 3 -> 0, 1, 3
console.log(duplicateCount("aABCbc33zzzzzqw((")) // 6 -> 3, a, b, c, z, (
console.log(duplicateCount("-,-\^\^((")) // 3 -> -, ^, (
```

Comment: Só lembrando que se a string tiver algum metacaractere de regex, esse deverá ser escapado com ``\``, caso contrário irá gerar uma regex inválida e dará erro. Ex: `duplicateCount('aab(((')`, o parênteses irá gerar a string `'(+'`, e isso é uma regex inválida , pois o parênteses deveria ser escrito como `\(` ([veja](https://repl.it/repls/RowdyBurdensomeParameter)). Se bem que a pergunta não deixa muito claro se é só letras (ela fala em "elementos repetidos", o que pode dar a entender que é qualquer coisa, embora só tenha letras nos exemplos). Enfim, meu pedantismo falando mais alto de novo...

Comment: Bem observado. Fiz um escape dos caracteres e acrescentei outra opção sem regex.

Answer (score -3):

Aqui está... tente assim e adapte para sua necessidade.

```js
function countLetter(char, sString) {
    if ( sString ) return sString.split("").reduce((acc, ch) => ch === char ? acc + 1: acc, 0); else return null;
}

let string = "aadbbcbcdcc";
console.log(
    [...new Set(string.split(""))].map((item) => {return item + "x" + countLetter(item, string)}).join("")
);
```

Comment: Leia a primeira linha da pergunta: *"O propósito é contabilizar o número de elementos que estão repetidos em uma string **e não** apenas verificar se há elementos duplicados ou **contar quantas vezes esses elementos aparecem**."*

Comment: Veja também esse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437867/contar-quantos-elementos-est%c3%a3o-duplicados-em-uma-string#comment845975_437867), esse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437867/contar-quantos-elementos-est%c3%a3o-duplicados-em-uma-string#comment845980_437867) e esse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437867/contar-quantos-elementos-est%c3%a3o-duplicados-em-uma-string#comment845982_437867) feitos pelo autor da pergunta.