# Como remover elementos repetidos de um array de objetos preservando o objeto que possuir propriedade id diferente de null

Tags: javascript

Preciso remover os elementos que possuir o mesmo valor na propriedade `screen_id` mantendo o que tiver a propriedade `id` diferente de `null`.

Meu objeto de exemplo:

```
let userPermissions  = [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: Cadastro de usuários,
        screen_id: 1,
        allow_read: true,
        allow_create: true,
        allow_update: false,
        allow_delete: true
    },
    {
        id: null,
        description: "Cadastro de usuários",
        screen_id: 1,
        allow_read: false,
        allow_create: false,
        allow_update: false,
        allow_delete: false
    },
    {
        id: null,
        description: "Tela teste 3",
        screen_id: 5,
        allow_read: false,
        allow_create: false,
        allow_update: false,
        allow_delete: false
    },
]
```

Eu preciso do seguinte resultado:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Cadastro de usuários",
        "screen_id": 1,
        "allow_read": true,
        "allow_create": true,
        "allow_update": false,
        "allow_delete": true
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "description": "Tela teste 3",
        "screen_id": 5,
        "allow_read": false,
        "allow_create": false,
        "allow_update": false,
        "allow_delete": false
    },
]
```

O que eu tentei:

```
userPermissions = userPermissions.reduce((arr, item) => {
  const removed = arr.filter(i => i['screen_id'] === item['screen_id'] && item['id'] !== null)
  return [...removed, item]
}, [])
```

Porém não está retornando o resultado conforme esperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de "legal", nem sempre é mais fácil pensar de maneira "funcional", então antes de tentar fazer com `reduce`, por que não usar um *loop* simples?

```js
let userPermissions  = [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: "Cadastro de usuários",
        screen_id: 1,
        allow_read: true,
        allow_create: true,
        allow_update: false,
        allow_delete: true
    },
    {
        id: null,
        description: "Cadastro de usuários",
        screen_id: 1,
        allow_read: false,
        allow_create: false,
        allow_update: false,
        allow_delete: false
    },
    {
        id: null,
        description: "Tela teste 3",
        screen_id: 5,
        allow_read: false,
        allow_create: false,
        allow_update: false,
        allow_delete: false
    }
];

let result = [];
let screenIdsJaVistos = {};
for (const u of userPermissions) {
    // se o screen_id ainda não foi verificado
    if (!screenIdsJaVistos[u.screen_id]) {
        // buscar todos que tem o mesmo screen_id
        let mesmoScreenId = userPermissions.filter(user => user.screen_id == u.screen_id);
        if (mesmoScreenId.length > 1) { // se tem mais de um, pega o que tem id não nulo
            result.push(mesmoScreenId.find(user => user.id !== null));
        } else { // senão, pega o próprio elemento
            result.push(u);
        }
        // esse screen_id já foi verificado, posso pular nas próximas iterações
        screenIdsJaVistos[u.screen_id] = true;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Claro que se tiver vários elementos com o mesmo `screen_id`, ele vai pegar o primeiro que não tem `id` nulo. Mas se precisar de outro critério de desempate, basta adicionar acima, dentro do `if (mesmoScreenId.length > 1)`.

Na minha opinião fica um código bem mais claro do que usando `reduce` <sup><sub>*mas claro que há quem discorde, por isso é "opinião"*</sub></sup> - além disso, fica mais fácil adicionar novas condições, caso necessário.

O código pode até ficar maior do que se usasse `reduce`, mas o tamanho do código não deve ser um fim por si só. [Um código mais claro e fácil de entender e manter é muito melhor que um código curto porém complicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052) (a menos que você e sua equipe se sintam confortáveis com `reduce`, claro).

Comment: Funciona bem neste exemplo porém se o primeiro screen_id repetido for id null, ele coloca esse elemento em vez do elemento que possui id !== null. Exemplo de reprodução: https://playcode.io/523408

Comment: @veroneseComS Foi um erro de digitação, no `filter` deveria ser `user.screen_id == u.screen_id` mas eu estava usando `u.id`. Já corrigi

Comment: Obrigado pela solução, agora ela atende minha necessidade e realmente, é mais fácil manter um código for() do que um código com reduce (eu ainda não tenho conhecimento das 1001 utilidades que um reducer pode fazer)

Comment: @veroneseComS Na minha opinião, existe um certo abuso do `reduce`, muita gente usa sem pensar, mesmo quando um loop simples é a melhor solução (sem contar que geralmente é mais lento também, embora para arrays pequenos a diferença seja insignificante).

Answer (score 3):

Se você quiser uma solução um pouco mais performática, pode utilizar um laço `for` convencional:

```js
const userPermissions = [
  { id: null, description: 'Tela teste 4', screen_id: 6 },
  { id: null, description: 'Cadastro de usuários', screen_id: 1 },
  { id: null, description: 'Tela teste 3', screen_id: 5 },
  { id: 8, description: 'Tela teste 4', screen_id: 6 },
  { id: 1, description: 'Cadastro de usuários', screen_id: 1 }
];

function removeDuplicates(list) {
  const listed = {};

  for (const item of list) {
    const { id, screen_id: screenId } = item;

    // Caso um item já esteja sido listado e seu ID não seja nulo, não será
    // adicionado à lista.
    if (screenId in listed && listed[screenId].id !== null) {
      continue;
    }

    // Caso ainda não esteja listado, ou já esteja listado, porém com um ID
    // nulo, será adicionado à lista.
    if (
      !(screenId in listed) ||
      (listed[screenId].id === null && id !== null) // Irá garantir que itens com ID não nulo sejam reinseridos.
    ) {
      listed[screenId] = item;
    }
  }

  return Object.values(listed);
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(userPermissions));
```

É um pouco verboso, mas como só tem um laço de iterações, creio que seja a melhor alternativa se você precisar de performance... Até dá para fazer com `reduce`, mas penso que ficaria meio <s>nojento</s>...

Comment: Dessa forma eu tenho sempre que garantir que o meu elemento que possui id !== null apareça primeiro que o elemento de id null, certo?

Comment: Eu tentei fazer com `reduce`, mas de fato estava ficando tão "nojento" que desisti :-)

Comment: Sim, @veroneseComS, os elementos que tiverem um ID ≠ nulo serão priorizados. A parte do código _responsável_ por isso é: `|| (listed[screenId] === null && id !== null)`, na expressão de avaliação do segundo `if`.

Comment: Eu fiz uns testes com seu código, se meu elemento repetido com id null aparece primeiro que o elemento repetido com id !== null, ele é inserido. Aqui há uma reprodução: https://playcode.io/523408

Comment: Realmente, @veroneseComS, erro meu. Perdão. :v Editei a resposta.

Comment: @LuizFelipe obrigado!