# Revisão de código da classe CPF em Java

Tags: java, revisão-de-código

Podem revisar o código da minha classe CPF?

Um ponto de crítica é o uso de regex que pode ser desnecessário. Mas a meu ver torna o código mais curto.

Outro ponto é a adoção de uma classe para isso, poderiam ser cálculos feitos isoladamente. Mas acho que encapsulado em uma classe fica melhor.

É só uma classe teórica, ela foi testada e funciona, mas não chegou a ser usada em produção. Aceita CPF's válidos ou sem dígito verificador, e gera CPF's aleatórios.

**Cpf.java**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Cpf {

    public static final int NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV = 9;
    public static final int NRO_DIGITOS_VERIFICADORES = 2;
    public static final int NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV = NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV + NRO_DIGITOS_VERIFICADORES;

    private final String cpf;

    /** Recebe uma cadeia completa de dígitos de CPF, sem formatação */
    public Cpf(String cpf) {
        if (cpf == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CPF não pode ser nulo.");
        } else if (ehCadeiaDeNoveDigitosNaoIniciadaEmZero(cpf)) {
            this.cpf = cpf + moduloOnze(cpf);
        } else if (ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(cpf) && isValido(cpf)) {
            this.cpf = cpf;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Número de CPF inválido: " + cpf);
        }
    }

    private static boolean ehCadeiaDeNoveDigitosNaoIniciadaEmZero(String cadeia) {
        return cadeia != null && cadeia.matches("[1-9]\\d{" + (NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV - 1) + "}");
    }

    private static boolean ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(String cadeia) {
        return cadeia != null && cadeia.matches("[1-9]\\d{" + (NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV - 1) + "}");
    }

    private static boolean isValido(String cpf) {
        return ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(cpf)
                && cpf.substring(NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV, NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV).
                        equals(moduloOnze(cpf.substring(0, NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV)));
    }

    /** Recebe uma cadeia de 9 dígitos decimais e retorna o módulo-11 dessa cadeia */
    private static String moduloOnze(String digitos) {
        if (false == ehCadeiaDeNoveDigitosNaoIniciadaEmZero(digitos)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dígitos de CPF inválidos: " + digitos);
        }

        int dv1 = calcularDigitoVerificador(digitos);
        int dv2 = calcularDigitoVerificador(digitos + dv1);

        return String.valueOf(dv1) + String.valueOf(dv2);
    }

    private static int calcularDigitoVerificador(String digitos) {
        int peso = digitos.length() + 1;
        int dv = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digitos.length(); i++) {
            dv += (digitos.charAt(i) - '0') * peso;
            peso--;
        }

        dv = 11 - (dv % 11);

        return dv > 9 ? 0 : dv;
    }

    /** Exibe o CPF em formato 999.999.999-99 */
    public String formatado() {
        return cpf.substring(0, 3) + "." +
                cpf.substring(3, 6) + "." +
                cpf.substring(6, NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV) + "-" +
                cpf.substring(NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV, NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV);
    }

    /** Exibe o CPF em formato 99999999999 (onze dígitos decimais) */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public String digitosVerificadores() {
        return cpf.substring(NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV);
    }

    public static Cpf criarAleatorio() {
        String noveDigitosAleatorios =
                String.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100_000_000, 999_999_999 + 1));
        return new Cpf(noveDigitosAleatorios + moduloOnze(noveDigitosAleatorios));
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Cpf cpf = new Cpf("526265690"); // Deve ter DV's 03
        System.out.println(cpf.formatado());
        System.out.println(cpf.digitosVerificadores());
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse código é curto? Então tá... :) O que eu já vi de problem a é a inconsistência do `is` e `eh`, eu usaria `é` :P Eu tenho um treco quando vejo um `false ==`. Mas você não usou RegEx pro cálculo que era o que estava sendo discutido no chat. Usou pra validação, aí até faz algum sentido, ainda que eu não usaria (eu faria em uma linha mais rápido e na minha opinião mais legível), mas não está estritamente errado usar. Fica a questão se precisa fazer essa validação isolada, se não precisa, aí está usando algo desnecessário. Huum, acabei de ver, tá tudo privado, então acho que é exagerado.

Comment: Tá com cara de modularização sem ganho algum. A função principal eu faço em 4 linhas :P, desde que não coloque mais nada nela como a validação. Por que a formatação não fez com RegEx? :P

Comment: A função principal que você fala é o cálculo do dígito né? Esse eu peguei da internet, dei uma guaribada só, não sei como ficaria mais curto. Mostra aí :P não entendi o problema que ocorre em ser tudo privado.

Comment: É que acontece aquilo que estávamos falando no chat, você valida e depois cria o dígito, dá pra fazer ao mesmo tempo. De início eu achei que era um método pra ser usado pelo consumidor da classe.

Comment: Talvez eu devesse ter me perguntado "o que é realmente necessário de responsabilidade para a classe?" antes de fazer, isso poderia ter mudado a cara dela, o que você acha? Eu fiz no achômetro, não no requisito real. Nunca trabalhei em algo que eu precisasse fazer uma classe para tratar CPF :P

Comment: _"Tá com cara de modularização sem ganho algum"_ Eu concordo, pelo que entendi o erro foi querer modularizar um candidato a entidade que não tem comportamento (responsabilidade) algum e pode muito bem ser um campo de uma outra entidade. Vê-se então que só porque um algoritmo é associado a um dado não quer dizer que eles devam estar juntos sempre, seria isso? Onde deveria ser validado o CPF então, no modelo de negócio? Em uma classe validadora? Ou dentro da entidade que o contém?

Comment: O problema é só ter esse monte de função, não vi motivo, parece ser só para parecer organizado, forçar o SRP, mas a responsabilidade é simples demais, por isso eu disse que dá pra fazer em 4 linhas. O problema não é o tipo, é a implementação.

Comment: Estou achando realmente que há um erro na modelagem, que CPF não deveria ser uma entidade. Foi nesse sentido que entendi a "modularização sem ganho algum", apesar de ter entendido agora que você falou dos métodos. Eu falo responsabilidade do sentido de interface pública, não da razão para mudar do SRP. Eu não vou pedir código de contra-exemplo porque dá trabalho escrever :P acho que consigo visualizar como ficaria um código mais curto, mas se quiser dar uma descrição para ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Ele pode ser sim, em muitos casos é vantajoso ser (ainda que em Java sempre será ruim :D) Essa entidade só está complexa demais, só precisa ser mais simples. Na verdade não lembro mais de todos detalhes e esfriei nisso, pode ser que a interface esteja boa, o problema é a implementação,

Comment: A interface (coisas que o objeto deve saber e fazer, "know" e "do", `getStuff()` e `doStuff()`) pelo exemplo é só exibir o CPF formatado (como o @hkotsubo fala na resposta dele) e gerar um número aleatório. Não sei se é uma interface muito significativa ou coerente.

Comment: Também tem o problema (eu não percebi, um colega apontou) que o construtor dispara exceção se o CPF é inválido, ou seja, está tratando fluxo de execução com exceções. Então como um CPF inválido não é uma situação excepcional (o usuário pode inserir facilmente um inválido), o mais certo seria ter algum tipo de validador.

Comment: @Piovezan Sobre a validação, é o que eu disse na resposta: "*Você quer que a classe represente um CPF, ou só quer um validador/calculador de dígitos verificadores? Se fosse o segundo caso, faria mais sentido uma classe utilitária com métodos públicos e estáticos, que retornam apenas true/false*". Mas se a ideia é representar um CPF válido, aí faria sentido lançar exceção, pois assim ela não deixaria criar instâncias inválidas (mas se puder ter uma instância com número inválido, aí não lançaria exceção, etc). Enfim, é o que já foi dito, sem requisitos reais, só nos resta especular :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Tem razão, desculpe, não tinha me atentado para essa parte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como é uma classe teórica (sem um requisito real), vou tomar como premissa que a responsabilidade dela é representar um CPF (e não somente validar ou formatar, pois aí algumas coisas poderiam ser mudadas, conforme discutido mais abaixo). Ou seja, eu passo uma `String` contendo um possível número de CPF e ela só cria a instância se esse número for válido (sendo que "válido" considera apenas se os dígitos verificadores estão corretos, caso existam - se não existir, a classe calcula automaticamente).

Se a ideia é somente essa, não precisa de regex, pois ela só está servindo para verificar se a `String` tem uma determinada quantidade de dígitos. Mas você pode fazer essa verificação durante o cálculo dos dígitos verificadores, economizando assim um *loop* desnecessário (a regex terá que varrer toda a `String` para verificar que ela só tem dígitos). Na verdade dá para economizar 2 *loops* (o da regex e um dos que calculam os dígitos verificadores), pois ambos os dígitos verificadores podem ser calculados no mesmo *loop*. Uma alternativa para o construtor e os métodos auxiliares usados por ele seria:

```
public Cpf(String cpf) {
    if (cpf == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("CPF não pode ser nulo.");
    } else if (cpf.length() != NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV && cpf.length() != NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Número de CPF deve ter " + NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV + " ou " + NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV + " dígitos");
    }
    this.cpf = verificaDigitos(cpf);
}

private static String verificaDigitos(String cpf) { // este método só é chamado depois que eu já sei que o tamanho da string é 9 ou 11
    int total1 = 0, total2 = 0;
    int multiplicador = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV; i++) { // percorre somente os 9 primeiros dígitos
        int c = cpf.charAt(i) - 48;
        if (c < 0 || c > 9) { // não é dígito de 0 a 9, inválido
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CPF deve ter somente dígitos: caractere inválido na posição " + i);
        }
        total1 += multiplicador * c;
        total2 += (multiplicador + 1) * c;
        multiplicador--;
    }
    int dv1 = dv(total1, 1, cpf);
    int dv2 = dv(total2 + dv1 * 2, 2, cpf);

    if (cpf.length() == NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV) { // tem 9 dígitos, concatenar os dígitos verificadores
        return cpf + dv1 + dv2;
    }
    return cpf; // se chegou aqui é porque tem 11 dígitos e os dígitos verificadores são válidos, então retorna sem modificações
}

// recebe o total, o número do dígito verificador (i pode ser 1 ou 2) e a string do CPF
// se o tamanho da string é 11, verifica se o dígito verificador calculado é o mesmo que está na string
private static int dv(int total, int i, String cpf) {
    int resto = total % 11;
    int dv = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    if (cpf.length() == NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV && dv != cpf.charAt(NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV - (3 - i)) - 48)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException((i == 1 ? "Primeiro" : "Segundo") + " dígito verificador não bate");

    return dv;
}
```

No método `verificaDigitos` eu faço apenas um *loop* pelos primeiros 9 dígitos, calculando as somatórias.

Um detalhe/curiosidade é que dentro do *loop* eu também poderia fazer assim:

```
if (i != 0) {
    total2 += (multiplicador + 1) * c;
}
```

Pode parecer estranho pular a multiplicação do primeiro dígito por 11 em `total2`, mas no final vamos calcular o resto da divisão por 11 e portanto o primeiro termo é redundante: se eu tiver um número `n` e fizer `n % 11`, o resultado será o mesmo que `(n + (11 * x)) % 11` (para qualquer `x` inteiro). Somar qualquer múltiplo de 11 não mudará o resto da divisão por 11, então somar "11 vezes o primeiro dígito" em `total2` não faz diferença (se bem que nesse caso, talvez esse `if` não passe de micro-otimização).

Depois de terminado o *loop*, eu vejo se o primeiro dígito verificador é igual ao do CPF informado, mas só se o tamanho da `String` for 11 (se for 9, não tem o que verificar). Se for válido, eu prossigo para o segundo dígito. Repare que no `if` do método `dv` eu nem preciso verificar se o décimo e décimo primeiro caracteres são dígitos de 0 a 9, pois se não forem, o valor com certeza não baterá com os dígitos verificadores.

Por fim, eu verifico se devo concatenar os dígitos no final da `String` (o que só deve ser feito se o tamanho dela for 9).

Com isso, o método que cria um CPF aleatório pode simplesmente trabalhar com strings de 9 dígitos (já que os dígitos verificadores serão calculados e concatenados dentro do próprio construtor):

```
public static Cpf criarAleatorio() {
    String noveDigitosAleatorios = String.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100_000_000, 999_999_999 + 1));
    return new Cpf(noveDigitosAleatorios);
}
```

Como nesse caso específico eu já sei que a `String` terá apenas dígitos, *talvez* valesse a pena refatorar a classe para separar a validação do cálculo dos dígitos verificadores, pois neste caso não preciso verificar que todos os caracteres são dígitos - *fica como "exercício para o leitor" :-)*.

---

Quanto à adoção de uma classe para isso, depende do objetivo. Você quer que a classe represente um CPF, ou só quer um validador/calculador de dígitos verificadores? Se fosse o segundo caso, faria mais sentido uma classe utilitária com métodos públicos e estáticos, que retornam apenas `true`/`false` (CPF válido ou inválido), ou se quiser ser mais específico, retornam códigos de erro que indiquem qual foi o problema (não tem dígitos, quantidade errada, dígitos verificadores não batem, etc). Outra alternativa seria encapsular esse código de erro em uma classe ou `enum` específico (`CpfValidationResult`?) caso valha a pena criar tal abstração (como é uma classe teórica sem requisito real, fica difícil opinar sobre o que é mais adequado).

Porém, se a ideia é que a classe represente um CPF, então eu acho que tudo bem lançar a exceção caso o CPF seja inválido (já que não parece fazer sentido criar uma instância se o número não é válido, pois aí ela deixaria de representar um CPF de fato - mas novamente, sem requisitos reais, não dá pra saber, vai que tem um requisito que permite ter "CPF's" com números inválidos, sei lá). Mas se fosse um validador, eu usaria uma das opções do parágrafo anterior, em vez de lançar uma exceção.

Por fim, o código nem ficou **tão** mais curto que o original, mas você não deve usar isso como critério principal para decidir qual implementação usar. [Código menor não é necessariamente "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052), tem que usar o que faz mais sentido em cada caso (e entendo que nesse caso não precisava usar regex, por exemplo). Sem contar que, [por mais que eu goste de regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:112052+%5Bregex%5D), usá-la [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/), além de gerar um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052) muitas vezes desnecessário.

Uma coisa que dá para melhorar são os nomes dos métodos `verificaDigitos` e `dv`, mas estou sem criatividade no momento (talvez `calculaEValidaDigitosVerificadores` e `calculaDigitoVerificador`, respectivamente? Não sei).

---

#### Se quiser continuar com a regex (e não mudar tanto o restante)

Se quiser **muito** continuar usando regex, uma *pequena* melhoria seria criá-las separadamente, já que cada chamada de `String::matches` compila a regex novamente. Mas como elas serão usadas várias vezes (toda vez que criar uma nova instância) e não mudam, então uma alternativa seria compilá-las apenas uma vez:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_9_DIGITOS = Pattern.compile("^\\d{9}$");
private static final Pattern REGEX_11_DIGITOS = Pattern.compile("^\\d{11}$");

private static boolean ehCadeiaDeNoveDigitosNaoIniciadaEmZero(String cadeia) {
    return REGEX_9_DIGITOS.matcher(cadeia).matches();
}

private static boolean ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(String cadeia) {
    return REGEX_11_DIGITOS.matcher(cadeia).matches();
}
```

Ou:

```
private static final Matcher REGEX_9_DIGITOS = Pattern.compile("^\\d{9}$").matcher("");
private static final Matcher REGEX_11_DIGITOS = Pattern.compile("^\\d{11}$").matcher("");

private static boolean ehCadeiaDeNoveDigitosNaoIniciadaEmZero(String cadeia) {
    return REGEX_9_DIGITOS.reset(cadeia).matches();
}

private static boolean ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(String cadeia) {
    return REGEX_11_DIGITOS.reset(cadeia).matches();
}
```

A diferença é que [a primeira opção com `Pattern` é *thread-safe*, enquanto a segunda (com `Matcher`) não](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/216324). Sem saber qual o cenário em que será usada a classe, não dá para sugerir qual o "melhor".

Detalhe que existem CPF's que começam com zero, e não considerar esses casos [pode dar problemas no mundo real](https://economia.uol.com.br/noticias/redacao/2020/04/27/auxilio-r-600-zero-cpf-some-confirmacao-do-pedido.htm). Por isso mudei suas regex, que não deixavam o CPF começar com zero. Agora elas só verificam se tem 9 ou 11 dígitos, sejam eles quais forem.

Os métodos `ehCadeiaEtc` não precisam verificar se a `String` é `null`, pois você só chama esses métodos em pontos onde já é garantido que não é.

Tem outro detalhe "estranho", neste `if` dentro do construtor:

```
else if (ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(cpf) && isValido(cpf))
```

É estranho porque dentro do método `isValido` temos:

```
private static boolean isValido(String cpf) {
    return ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(cpf) && cpf.substring(NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV, NRO_DIGITOS_COM_DV).equals(moduloOnze(cpf.substring(0, NRO_DIGITOS_SEM_DV)));
}
```

Ou seja, `ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos(cpf)` é chamado duas vezes, desnecessariamente. Decida onde é melhor chamá-lo (no `if` ou dentro de `isValido`) e faça-o somente uma vez. Decida também se vai usar o prefixo `eh` ou `is` (tanto faz, desde que seja consistente em todo o código).

E dá para ficar elucubrando eternamente sobre várias coisas: as constantes `NRO_DIGITOS_etc` são realmente necessárias? Se forem, precisam ser públicas? Os métodos `private` também precisam ser `static`? (funcionalmente, não faz diferença, já que nenhum deles altera ou acessa o estado da instância) A mesma classe que representa o CPF deveria ser responsável pela formatação e criação de uma instância aleatória? E por aí vai... (e sem requisitos reais, fica difícil decidir ou opinar algo - mesmo com requisitos já seria uma discussão boa)

Comment: Bastante detalhado @hkotsubo, obrigado. Não sabia desse requisito de aceitar 0 no início do CPF, devo ter pego o algoritmo de fonte ruim, ou pior, deduzi isso de alguma maneira. :P Tem que tomar cuidado com os requisitos. Não faço questão do regex, mas achei um pouco exagerado otimizar o número de loops, não precisava tanto :) Dar-me-ia por satisfeito com um loop só para validar os dígitos, ficaria mais claro, na minha opinião. E bem observada a chamada de `ehCadeiaDeOnzeDigitos()`, como vê, eu não estava preocupado com performance. :)

Comment: @Piovezan É, calcular os 2 dígitos no mesmo loop talvez seja micro-otimização também, mas achei válido mencionar que é perfeitamente possível, e sem complicar demais o código :-)

Comment: Dado o cenário que o CPF tem um tamanho conhecido de 11 caracteres o ganho de performance ao fazer apenas um loop é imperceptível. Vale lembrar também que existe uma conta sendo feita onze vezes nesse loop aumentando um pouco o tempo de processamento também, de maneira ínfima considerado o cenário da mesma maneira que economizar no loop. Algo que eu não fiz o benchmarking, mas pode ter um ganho de performance é a validação se o o caractere corrente é numérico ou não sem usar um Pattern (declarado como constante). Eu só usaria o método isDigit da classe Character pra verificar.