# Como utilizar reduce em um array de objetos em React

Tags: javascript, react, objetos

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const fruits = [
        { name: "banana", cor: "yellow", price: 2 },
        { name: "cherry", cor: "red", price: 3 },
        { name: "strawberry", cor: "red", price: 4 },
      ]
  

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <div id="all fruit names"></div>
      <div id="red fruit names"></div>
      <div id="total"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Eu preciso somar o valor dos preços das frutas, mas não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do objeto. Quando uso map ele retorna os números mas na forma de string.

Answer (score 2):

Inicialmente te recomendo uma leitura sobre [Como não fazer perguntas no Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas), irei responder a mesma de acordo com o que entendi pelo titulo da pergunta usando o método [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para somar os valores no array desejado.

```js
const fruits = [
  { name: "banana", cor: "yellow", price: 2 },
  { name: "cherry", cor: "red", price: 3 },
  { name: "strawberry", cor: "red", price: 4 },
];

// acumulador é a variável que mantem o valor da soma dos seus items, que neste caso começa de 0 e a cada iteração é somado o valor o objeto atual
const result = fruits.reduce(function (acumulador, objetoAtual){
  return acumulador + objetoAtual.price;
}, 0);

// Este irá produzir o mesmo resultado porem usando uma Arrow Function
const result2 = fruits.reduce((a, b) => a + b.price, 0);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta é sobre como usar [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (e [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466258/112052) já explicou como fazê-lo), mas na verdade você não precisa dele. Um *loop* simples já resolve:

```
let total = 0;
for (const fruit of fruits) {
    total += fruit.price;
}
// usar o total do jeito que quiser
```

Ou o `for` mais tradicional:

```
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    total += fruits[i].price;
}
```

Só isso.

---

> "*Ah, mas eu **quero** usar `reduce`.*"

Pra que? Será que precisa mesmo? A menos que estejam te "obrigando", eu não vejo nenhuma razão técnica ou prática para usá-lo em vez de um *loop* simples (a não ser talvez por gosto pessoal, ou "boas práticas", ou "*paradigma funcional é mais legal*", etc). Talvez te digam que é "*melhor porque tem menos linhas*":

```
let total = fruits.reduce((a, b) => a + b.price, 0);
```

Mas ["código menor" não é necessariamente "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052). Até porque `reduce` geralmente será mais lento que um `for` simples (claro que para poucos arrays pequenos, a diferença será insignificante e imperceptível, mas aumente o tamanho deles e [a diferença se torna evidente](https://jsperf.com/somar-reduce-vs-loops/1)).

---

Apenas para deixar claro que não sou contra o uso de `reduce` em si. Só acho que é "super valorizado", e nem sempre é necessário (para somar elementos de um array, definitivamente eu acho um exagero).

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` sobre um array para criar uma lista de componentes para cada item.

Use `filter` para filtrar um array, de acordo com determinado critério. Por exemplo, para listar apenas as frutas vermelhas.

Use `reduce` para transformar um array em um valor, que pode ser um número, um objeto, etc. No caso, para transformar uma lista num total de preços.

Opcionalmente, use `React.useMemo` para memorizar um cálculo, em caso de re-renderização, refazendo-o apenas caso a lista de dependências mude.

[Demo no codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-moon-mjzet?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Component = ({ fruits }) => {
  const redFruits = useMemo(() => fruits.filter(item => item.cor === "red"), [
    fruits
  ]);

  const total = useMemo(() => fruits.reduce((a, b) => a + b.price, 0), [
    fruits
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
      <div id="all-fruit-names">
        {fruits.map(item => (
          <p>
            {item.name} ({item.price})
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div id="red-fruit-names" style={{ color: "red" }}>
        {redFruits.map(item => (
          <p>{item.name}</p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div id="total">Total: {total}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```