# Regex que aceite somente letras ou letras e números

Tags: java, regex, validação

Estou tentando fazer uma regex em Java que aceite:

- somente letras;
- letras e números
- não pode ter somente números
- não pode ter caracteres de pontuação ou especial

A minha dificuldade é que não consigo fazer uma regex que aceite, por exemplo, `l0v3y0oplj` ou `1ads967bjk`. Vou mostrar o meu código, até o momento:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)");
       Matcher a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;
               a=p.matcher("admin");       //eu quero que seja TRUE
               b=p.matcher("l0v3y0oplj");   //eu quero que seja TRUE
               c=p.matcher("123admin");      //eu quero que seja TRUE
               d=p.matcher("123ADMIN?");      //eu quero que seja FALSE
               e=p.matcher("123ADMIN");       //eu quero que seja TRUE
               f=p.matcher("am.ouy?");  //eu quero que seja FALSE
               g=p.matcher("12345678909776apouatgb");    //eu quero que seja TRUE
               h=p.matcher("1ads967bjk");  //eu quero que seja TRUE
               i=p.matcher("ADMIN123");  //eu quero que seja TRUE
               j=p.matcher("123");      //eu quero que seja FALSE
               
               System.out.println("A matches: "+a.matches());//resultado: TRUE
               System.out.println("B matches: "+b.matches());//resultado: FALSE
               System.out.println("C matches: "+c.matches());//resultado: TRUE
               System.out.println("D matches: "+d.matches());//resultado: FALSE
               System.out.println("E matches: "+e.matches());//resultado: TRUE
               System.out.println("F matches: "+f.matches());//resultado: FALSE
               System.out.println("G matches: "+g.matches());//resultado: TRUE
               System.out.println("H matches: "+h.matches());//resultado: FALSE
               System.out.println("I matches: "+i.matches());//resultado: TRUE
               System.out.println("J matches: "+j.matches());//resultado: FALSE
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na minha opinião, este problema é mais simples de resolver sem regex, mas de qualquer forma, vamos ver uma solução com e outra sem, aí você tira suas próprias conclusões.

---

O problema da sua regex é que ela só considera alguns casos:

- `[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+` significa "zero ou mais números, seguido de uma ou mais letras"
- `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*` significa "uma ou mais letras, seguido de zero ou mais números"

Estas opções fazem parte de uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) - o caractere `|`, que significa "ou" - então a regex verifica as opções isoladamente, da esquerda para a direita (se não der na primeira, tenta a segunda, se não der nenhuma, ela falha e nenhum *match* é encontrado).

Ou seja, se tiver letras, números, e depois outras letras (ou números, letras, e depois outros números), a regex já não considera, pois isso não se encaixa em nenhum dos casos. Por isso ela falha em casos como `l0v3y0oplj` e `1ads967bjk`.

Por exemplo, em `1ads967bjk`, primeiro a regex tenta com a opção `[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+`, então o trecho `[0-9]*` pega o número `1`, depois `[a-zA-Z]+` pega o trecho `ads`, e depois não há nenhum trecho da expressão para pegar do `9` em diante. Então ela tenta o segundo trecho da alternância (`[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`), mas como a string começa com número, ela já falha logo no `[a-zA-Z]+`. Sendo assim, a string não corresponde à expressão.

Uma forma de resolver é considerar que no início e no fim podem ter zero ou mais letras ou números, e no meio tem que ter pelo menos uma letra. Ou seja:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

Isto é basicamente o que foi sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466318/112052), a diferença é que ela não considerou as letras maiúsculas. Mas se quiser, você também pode deixar a expressão apenas com letras minúsculas e usar a [opção `CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), assim a regex também vai considerar letras maiúsculas:

```
// Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE para não diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Ou ainda, o intervalo `0-9` pode ser trocado pelo [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` (lembrando que dentro de strings o caractere `\` deve ser escrito como `\\`):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z\\d]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\\d]*$");
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string, assim eu garanto que a string só pode ter o que está na regex (tudo bem que [`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) sempre verifica a string inteira, mas eu tenho o hábito de [deixar claro na regex](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) quando estou verificando a string toda ou não).

Depois temos `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` (o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` indica "zero ou mais", então aqui temos zero ou mais letras ou números). Depois temos `[a-zA-Z]+` (o quantificador `+` indica "um ou mais", então aqui temos uma ou mais letras, ou seja, estou garantindo que deve ter pelo menos uma letra). Por fim, temos novamente zero ou mais letras ou números.

Assim, eu garanto que posso ter letras, depois números, depois mais letras, depois mais números, etc. Repare que eu nem precisei tratar da condição "*não pode ter caracteres de pontuação ou especial*", pois ao colocar só o que eu quero (letras ou números), automaticamente qualquer outro caractere que não seja letra ou número já é rejeitado.

---

Outra alternativa (um pouco mais complicada) é:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?![0-9]+$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

Esta regex usa [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que servem para verificar se algo existe ou não à frente:

- `(?![0-9]+$)`: este é um *lookahead* negativo que verifica se algo **não** existe à frente. E esse algo é `[0-9]+$` (ou seja, um ou mais números, até o final da string). Então isso serve para verificar se a regex só tem dígitos (e se tiver, a regex falha)
- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`: este é um *lookahead* positivo que verifica se algo existe à frente. E esse algo é `.*[a-zA-Z]`, ou seja, zero ou mais caracteres (`.*`) seguido de uma letra. Então isso serve para verificar se tem uma letra em algum lugar da string (ou seja, garante que exista pelo menos uma letra)

O detalhe do *lookahead* é que ele só verifica o que está à frente e depois volta onde estava e continua verificando o restante. E como eles estão logo depois do `^`, a verificação é feita no início da string. Depois que eles fazem as verificações, a regex prossegue e verifica `[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` (uma ou mais letras ou números, até o final da string).

Por ficar "indo e voltando" na string, a regex com *lookaheads* é um pouco mais lenta que a primeira (compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/xE779B/2/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/poy0M3/3/)). Mas claro que para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença será imperceptível.

---

Vale lembrar também que estas soluções não consideram letras acentuadas nem de outros alfabetos. **Se quiser** ser mais abrangente e considerar isso também, uma opção é usar [*Unicode properties*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{L}\\p{N}]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\p{N}]*$");
```

No caso, `\p{L}` são todas as letras definidas pelo Unicode (são todas as categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)), e `\p{N}` são todos os dígitos  definidos pelo Unicode (que vai além dos dígitos de `0` a `9`, veja a lista completa [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm), [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) e [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm)).

Ou seja, é a mesma ideia da primeira regex: no início e no fim podem ter zero ou mais letras ou números, e no meio tem que ter pelo menos uma letra. O que muda é apenas a definição do que é uma "letra" e um "número".

Com esta regex, passarão a ser consideradas válidas strings como `"親41áç123Ã۹"` (o caractere `۹` é um dos que são considerados "dígitos" pelo Unicode - [veja aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06f9/index.htm) a definição do mesmo).

---

#### Sem regex

Mas como eu já disse, talvez seja mais fácil fazer sem regex. Basta percorrer os caracteres da string e ir fazendo as verificações:

```
public boolean verifica(String s) {
    boolean temLetra = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        boolean isLetra = ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z');
        if (isLetra && !temLetra) // se tem pelo menos uma letra
            temLetra = true;
        if (! (('0' <= c && c <= '9') || isLetra)) // se não é número nem letra, nem precisa verificar o resto
            return false;
    }
    return temLetra;
}

...
System.out.println(verifica("admin")); // true
```

No *loop* eu vejo se tem alguma letra, e ao mesmo tempo verifico se é uma letra ou número. Se no meio eu encontrar algo que não é número nem letra, eu já retorno `false` (pois eu já sei que é inválido e aí nem adianta verificar o restante). Esta solução funciona para todos os casos que você mencionou (mas não considera letras acentuadas nem de outros alfabetos, como o exemplo anterior com *Unicode properties*).

Se quiser considerar todas as letras e dígitos definidos pelo Unicode, pode usar os métodos [`isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) e [`isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) da classe [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html):

```
public boolean verifica(String s) {
    boolean temLetra = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        boolean isLetra = Character.isLetter(c);
        if (isLetra && !temLetra) // se tem pelo menos uma letra
            temLetra = true;
        if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || isLetra)) // se não é número nem letra, nem precisa verificar o resto
            return false;
    }
    return temLetra;
}
```

À primeira vista, o código acima pode parecer pior porque a solução com regex "tem menos linhas", mas [código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052). Regex tem um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052) que muitas vezes não é percebido (ainda mais para strings pequenas sendo verificadas poucas vezes, a diferença acaba sendo imperceptível), mas dependendo da situação, pode sim ser um gargalo de desempenho.

Regex é legal e [eu particularmente gosto bastante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:112052+%5Bregex%5D), mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 0):

Eu simplificaria seus pontos "a", "b", "c" e "d", por:

1. Letras e Números
2. Números são opcionais
3. Não pode ser vazia

E esta expressão é a resposta:

```
^[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$
```

Você pode [testa-la aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Qb2Zkg/1).