# Tem como usar métodos dentro de outros métodos em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, for

Gostaria de saber se em Python é possível criar um laço de repetição `for` dentro de um `format()`?

**Exemplo**

```
#Considerando:

z=(1,2,3,4)

print(f'''os números pares  foram {
    for i%2==0 in z:
        print(i,end='são números pares')
}''')
```

Não consigo saber se estou fazendo isso da forma correta ou se simplesmente não tem como fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer imprimir tudo de uma vez, você pode usar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) junto com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
z = (1,2,3,4)
print(f'os números pares foram: {", ".join(str(i) for i in z if i % 2 == 0)} são números pares')
```

No caso, o `join` irá usar a string `", "` para separar os números (ou seja, eles serão escritos com uma vírgula e espaço entre eles). Tive que usar [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) para transformar os números em strings, senão `join` dá erro.

O resultado é uma string com os números pares, separados por vírgula e espaço. Isto imprime:

> os números pares foram: 2, 4 são números pares

---

Claro que dependendo do tamanho da expressão, pode ficar confuso colocar tudo de uma vez dentro da [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). Sendo assim, pode ficar menos confuso se você fizer desta maneira:

```
z = (1,2,3,4)
pares = ", ".join(str(i) for i in z if i % 2 == 0)
print(f'os números pares foram: {pares} são números pares')
```

Pode ter ficado com uma linha a mais, mas [código com menos linhas nem sempre é "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052).

---

Outra opção é criar uma lista, assim:

```
print(f'os números pares foram: {[i for i in z if i % 2 == 0]} são números pares')
```

Repare nos colchetes em volta do `for`. Isso criará uma lista com os números pares, e esta lista será impressa. A diferença é que nesse caso a saída será:

> os números pares foram: [2, 4] são números pares

Pois ao imprimir diretamente a lista, os elementos são mostrados assim, entre colchetes. Não deixa de ser uma opção, mas usando `join` (ou qualquer outro método que monte a string antes de ser impressa) você tem mais controle sobre o formato desejado.

Comment: Desculpe por não dar nenhuma contribuição para sua resposta apesar de ter ajudado bastante eu ainda não tenho reputação suficiente :P

Comment: @JoãoGustavo Na verdade, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Interessante cara! Vlw pelo link, então aproveitando que a resposta foi bem pertinente já vou aceitar. Mas sobre a questão mais generalista dos métodos sabe me dizer se é pertinente ou possível?

Comment: @JoãoGustavo Pra contar quantas vezes um número ocorre, existe o [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (se entendi bem o que vc está tentando fazer). Enfim, é como eu disse, se tem outra dúvida, por favor [faça outra pergunta](/questions/ask) - **não esquecendo de pesquisar antes**, pois já tem várias perguntas sobre `Counter` no site :-) (a menos que sua dúvida seja outra, claro, eu não entendi bem se o problema é a contagem ou outra coisa).

Comment: @JoãoGustavo Digo pra vc fazer outra pergunta (depois de pesquisar e ter certeza que não existe essa pergunta no site) para deixar o site mais organizado (uma pergunta por dúvida específica), e também porque perguntas novas ficam visíveis para todos na página principal, o que aumenta as chances de ter uma resposta (já aqui nos comentários só eu vou ver)

Comment: Na verdade são realmente problemas diferentes que eu coloquei em pauta assim que trouxe a primeira discussão, mas realmente as chances de serem resolvidos é mais se eu reestrutura-los como diferentes questões na página principal.  Farei isso, obrigado aí :D.

Comment: Existe também a possibilidade do uso de funções recursivas. Cria-se o método dentro de uma função, onde a função pode executar a si mesma

Comment: @yoyo No caso desta pergunta, não acho que faça sentido usar recursão...

Answer (score 0):

**Nossa cara eu usei essas novas formas e deu muito certo pra mim! Grato de mais, aliás eu também gostaria de saber se pudesse, qual seria a forma mais limpa e menos pesada de usar o código:**

**(para dizer a verdade estou começando e não conheço as melhores formas de se escrever a resolução, então outra forma de responder minha dúvida pode ser indicando algum material sobre o assunto)**

> *1º Usando um laço já necessário para aninhar um if e realizar a tarefa de extrair os números pares.*

```
c3=p3=c9=0

par=('')

n1=int(input('Digite aqui o 1º valor: '))
n2=int(input('Agora o 2º: '))
n3=int(input('O 3º: '))
n4=int(input('E o 4º: '))

z=(n1,n2,n3,n4)

print(f'você digitou os valores {z}')


for nx in z:

    if (nx/9)==1:
        c9+=1
    
    if (nx/3)==1:
        p3=z.index(3)+1
        c3+=1

    else:
        pass

    if nx%2==0:
        par+=' '+str(nx)+' '

b=par

print(f'o nove apareceu {c9} vezes na tupla')


if p3>1:
    print(f'o número 3 apareceu {p3} vezes na tupla e pela primeira vez no {p3}º espaço na tupla')

elif p3==0:
    print('o valor 3 não apareceu em nenhuma posição')

else:
    print(f'o número 3 apareceu {1} vez na tupla na {p3}º posição')


print(f'os números pares  foram: {b}')
```

> *2ºCriar um novo laço dentro do meu print evitando mais um loop acima porém criando um novo loop abaixo.*

```
c3=p3=c9=0

par=('')

n1=int(input('Digite aqui o 1º valor: '))
n2=int(input('Agora o 2º: '))
n3=int(input('O 3º: '))
n4=int(input('E o 4º: '))

z=(n1,n2,n3,n4)

print(f'você digitou os valores {z}')


for nx in z:

    if (nx/9)==1:
        c9+=1
    
    if (nx/3)==1:
        p3=z.index(3)+1
        c3+=1

    else:
        pass


print(f'o nove apareceu {c9} vezes na tupla')


if p3>1:
    print(f'o número 3 apareceu {p3} vezes na tupla e pela primeira vez no {p3}º espaço na tupla')

elif p3==0:
    print('o valor 3 não apareceu em nenhuma posição')

else:
    print(f'o número 3 apareceu {1} vez na tupla na {p3}º posição')


print(f'os números pares  foram: {[nx for nx in z if nx%2==0]}')
```

Comment: João, a ideia do site é ter uma dúvida/problema específico por pergunta, e que este espaço seja usado apenas para respostas (ou seja, para soluções à sua pergunta inicial). Se tem outra dúvida, por favor [faça outra pergunta](/questions/ask)

Comment: De qq forma, uma maneira de simplificar seria: https://ideone.com/oNC1Fl

Comment: gostei bastante, deu uma simplificada na solução!