# "import pacote.*" em Java é bom ou ruim?

Tags: java, desempenho, característica-linguagem, import

Percebi que muitos programadores realizam os `import`'s em Java da seguinte forma:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

Enquanto eu ainda importo recurso por recurso:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
```

A minha dúvida é se realizar o `import` com `.*` gera benefício, por ter menos linhas no código, ou se gera consequências (como perda de performance) pelo código estar importando mais classes do que o necessário.

Comment: você gerencia os `imports` na mão?

Comment: sim, no caso eu vou importando o que estou usando. E se por algum motivo eu deixo de utilizar aquele import a IDE avisa e eu apago ele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Não tem perda de performance.

## Resposta longa

O [`import`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) serve para que você não precise digitar o *fully qualified name* ("nome completo") da classe (por exemplo, poder fazer `Date d = new Date();` em vez de `java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();`), e eles são resolvidos em tempo de compilação.

Ao fazer um `import pacote.*`, os nomes das classes daquele pacote ficam disponíveis para o compilador, mas isso não quer dizer que as classes em si serão carregadas. O código não vai ficar mais lento por causa disso.

**Talvez** o uso do `.*` cause uma pequena demora na compilação, mas **provavelmente será irrisório e imperceptível, e eu diria que é o menor dos problemas**. Sugiro se preocupar com coisas que realmente afetam a performance, ou seja, se realmente tem um problema, faça testes adequados para descobrir onde está o gargalo. A causa da performance ruim certamente **não** será o `import`.

---

Os motivos para escolher não usar `.*` são outros. Um é deixar bem claro quais classes você está usando, o que não deixa de ser uma "documentação automática" para quem for dar manutenção no código (logo no início da classe eu já vejo o que ela está usando).

Outro é que pode ocorrer colisão de nomes. Um exemplo clássico são as classes `java.util.Date` e `java.sql.Date`. Se eu fizer `import java.util.*;` e `import java.sql.*;`, o código não compila, pois duas classes com o mesmo nome estarão disponíveis e compilador não saberá como resolver a ambiguidade. Uma solução é importar explicitamente uma delas e usar a outra com o *fully qualified name* (por exemplo, fazer `import java.util.Date` e no código eu uso `Date` quando quero esta classe, e `java.sql.Date` quando quero a outra).

Também podem ocorrer colisões se você importa um pacote com `.*` e posteriormente alguém adiciona uma classe neste pacote que colide com alguma outra (de outro pacote) que você está usando.

Estas deveriam ser as preocupações ao optar por um ou outro. **A quantidade de linhas é irrelevante** (para muitos casos, aliás, [código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052)), esqueça isso. Eu pessoalmente prefiro não usar `.*`, principalmente pelo primeiro motivo (auto-documentar, deixar bem claro o que está sendo usado).

A maioria das IDE's modernas possuem formas de fazer `import`'s automaticamente, organizar por ordem alfabética, etc (e se quiser, muitas permitem que você configure se quer `.*` ou não). Muitas inclusive removem os `import`'s que não estão sendo usados (embora também não interfira na performance, pode deixar o código mais confuso, ao listar classes que não são usadas em lugar algum).

---

Só para mostrar que não há diferença, criei uma classe simples:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Compilei com `javac Teste.java` (OpenJDK 11.0.20.1) e depois usei a [ferramenta `javap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) para ver o *bytecode* gerado - o comando, no caso, é `javap -c Teste`.

O resultado foi:

```
public class Teste {
  public Teste();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: return
}
```

Depois mudei para `import java.util.*`:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

E o *bytecode* gerado foi **exatamente o mesmo**.

Por fim, fiz uma versão sem `import`:

```java
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.List<Object> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

E o *bytecode* gerado também foi idêntico.

---

Para saber mais:

- [Performance difference between a wild card import and the required class import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7128348)
- [Java import vs code performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5125404)
- [Any reason to clean up unused imports in Java, other than reducing clutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979057)